# regular expression to avoid only special chars

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm validating a input text box. I'm new to regexp. I want an expression which throws a validation error if all the characters of input are special characters. but it should allow special characters in the string.

-(**&^&)_) ----> invalid.

abcd-as jasd12 ----> valid.

currently validating for numbers and alphabets with `/^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-z A-Z 0-9 -]*$/`

Comment: What are special characters?

Comment: Which special characters do you want to allow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use negative Lookahead:

```
if (/^(?![\s\S]*[^\w -]+)[\s\S]*?$/im.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dP3vT1)

**EXPLANATION:**

^(?!.*[^\w -]+).*?$

```
Assert position at the beginning of a line (at beginning of the string or after a line break character) «^»
Assert that it is impossible to match the regex below starting at this position (negative lookahead) «(?!.*[^\w -]+)»
   Match any single character «.*»
      Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
   Match a single character NOT present in the list below «[^\w -]+»
      Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
      A word character (letters, digits, and underscores) «\w»
      The character “ ” « »
      The character “-” «-»
Match any single character «.*?»
   Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy) «*?»
Assert position at the end of a line (at the end of the string or before a line break character) «$»
```

Answer (score 2):

`/[A-Za-z0-9]/` will match positive if the string contains at least 1 letter or number, which should be the same as what you're asking.  If there are NO letters or numbers, that regex will evaluate as false.

Comment: You don't need `.*` around it.

Comment: Right you are.  Editing now, dunno what I was thinking in the first place.

Comment: does this allow spaces and special chars in between??

Comment: You pass it a string, it will check that string to make sure it contains at least 1 letter or number anywhere in the string, regardless of the other characters.

Answer (score 2):

According to your comment, special characters are `!@#$%^&*()_-`, so you could use:

```
var regex = /^[!@#$%^&*()_-]+$/;
if (regex.test(string)) 
    // all char are special
```

If you have more special char, add them in the character class.

Answer (score 1):

`~[^a-zA-z0-9 ]+~` it will matches if the String doesnot contains atleast one alphabets and numbers and spaces in it.

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/nE1lN4)